# Statusbar doesn't show message immediately and sometimes crash

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

I created an interface in pyqt4 designer, there is only a button and a status bar. I want to show a message in the status bar when I click the button. For some reason I have to put this action in a new thread.

But when I click the button, nothing happened. The message didn't appear until I drag the edge of the window. Sometimes the click action even cause the program to crash:

> ```
> pythonw.exe has stopped working.
> ```

This happens frequently, especially when I click too fast.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import threading

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def cal(self):
        self.statusbar.showMessage('something')   

    def onbutton(self):

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.cal)
        thread.start()



    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(510, 409)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 171, 91))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onbutton)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Most Qt objects cannot be updated from a worker thread, only the main thread. Based on your description I think QStatusBar is such an object.  Therefore you must arrange for the main thread to be notified when the worker thread wants to display a message.  How to do this depends on your application, but you should look at QCoreApplication.postEvent and QThread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crash happens because you are interacting with the Qt GUI from a secondary thread. You are only allowed to interact with the GUI from the main thread (see the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy)).

You have two options:

1. Switch to a PyQt `QThread`, and emit a signal from the thread. If the signal is connected to a slot in the main thread, then you can do the GUI interaction there. This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29269539/1994235) demonstrates approximately how to do this.
2. Use `QApplication.postEvent()` to send an event from the Python thread to the main thread, which then causes a method to be run which interacts with the GUI. Note that some people have concerns that this is not OK (see [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1645666/1994235)), however I've had no issue with it. I've wrapped this up in an freely available library called [`qtutils`](https://bitbucket.org/philipstarkey/qtutils/overview) (documentation [here](https://bitbucket.org/philipstarkey/qtutils/wiki/invoke_in_main)).